# JavaFx OnError MediaView Memory leak

Tags: memory, javafx, mediaview

I have software that I am working on that uses JavaFx MediaPlayers and MediaViews to create a UI.  For this to work the way we want we are reusing the MediaPlayers (after keeping them stored in a static class's hashMap) and then we place the MediaPlayer in new MediaViews when needed.  When the MediaView is done we set it to null and move on, but this has lead to a memory leak where the number of players will stay constant but the mediaViews will increase.  I made a minimal working version of this code so you can see the memory go up and up without collecting any mediaViews.   It seems like the getOnError or the Error property from the MediaPlayer is holding onto an old reference of the MediaView.  I would like to remove this, but it seems like you have to dispose of a mediaPlayer if you want to clean up all of it's memory, but I would like to save the Player and delete the View.

Here is some code that recreates the issue.  Just hit the stop button a few times which will remove the old mediaView and add a new one, but none ever get cleaned up.

```
package JavaFx;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class FxMediaExample1 extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public MediaView mediaView;
    public Scene scene;
    public VBox root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        // Locate the media content in the CLASSPATH


        // Create a Media
        File file  = new File("file:///C:/Users/Samuel%20Johnston/Downloads/cf86c6a4-271f-4dcb-bb11-fc30f5eb6b45_web.mp4");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Boobs");
        } else {
            System.out.println("poop");
        }
        Media media = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Samuel%20Johnston/Downloads/cf86c6a4-271f-4dcb-bb11-fc30f5eb6b45_web.mp4");
        media.setOnError(() -> {

            System.out.println("WHAT THE WHAT, " + media.getError().toString());
            System.out.println("WHAT THE WHAT, " + media.getError().getMessage());
            System.out.println("WHAT THE WHAT, " + media.getError().getStackTrace().toString());
            System.out.println("WHAT THE WHAT, " + media.getError().getLocalizedMessage());
        });
        // Create a Media Player
        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.setOnError(() -> {
            System.out.println("WHY THE WHY, " + player.getError().toString());
            System.out.println("WHY THE WHY, " + player.getError().getMessage());
            System.out.println("WHY THE WHY, " + player.getError().getStackTrace().toString());
            System.out.println("WHY THE WHY, " + player.getError().getLocalizedMessage());
        });
        // Automatically begin the playback
        player.setAutoPlay(true);

        // Create a 400X300 MediaView
        mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        mediaView.setFitWidth(700);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(700);
        mediaView.setSmooth(true);

        // Create the Buttons
        Button playButton = new Button("Play");
        Button stopButton = new Button("Stop");

        // Create the Event Handlers for the Button
        playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if (player.getStatus() == Status.PLAYING)
                {
                    player.stop();
                    player.play();
                }
                else
                {
                    player.play();
                }
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                player.stop();
                root.getChildren().remove(mediaView);
                mediaView = new MediaView(player);
                mediaView.setFitWidth(700);
                mediaView.setFitHeight(700);
                mediaView.setSmooth(true);
                root.getChildren().add(mediaView);

            }
        });

        // Create the HBox
        HBox controlBox = new HBox(5, playButton, stopButton);

        // Create the VBox
        root = new VBox(5,mediaView,controlBox);

        // Set the Style-properties of the HBox
        root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");

        // Create the Scene
        scene = new Scene(root);
        // Add the scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the title of the Stage
        stage.setTitle("A simple Media Example");
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create new `MediaView`s? Why not have a single view, and only change which `MediaPlayer` it is displaying?

Comment: We have several slides in a playlist we display.  Each video in a slide gets it's own MediaView and the playlist can be large enough that we need to dynamically load and delete the slides.  In the real example we will have multiple different videos getting cycled without any guarantee that the slides will even have a video.
The testing example ignores that since it isn't causing the leak if it is leaking without it.

Comment: You could still have a single, or finitely-many `MediaView` instances which are reused, similar to virtualized nodes in a `ListView`. If this is not possible for some other reason, setting the `player` property of a `MediaView` to `null` before disposing of it may help...

Comment: So I cannot set the MediaView player to null when I am deleting because I iterate through the list of objects attached to a slide and run a delete method over them.  This will cause a ConcurrentModificationException which breaks the program.

I'll try reusing the MediaViews similar to how I reuse the MediaPlayers and see if that helps